# Limiting records to first 10 instances in EJS template

Tags: express, ejs

I'm trying to limit the data rendered in an EJS view to the first 10 instances. Any ideas how I might do this? Here is my code:

```
<% if (product.reviews.length > 0) { %>
   <% product.reviews.map((review) => { %>
    <div>
      <p><%= formatDateI(review.createdAt) %></p>
      <p><%= review.comment %></p>
      <p><%= review.name %></p>
    </div>
   <% }) %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add index to the map function and return content only for index lower than 10

```
<% if (product.reviews.length > 0) { %>
   <% product.reviews.map((review, index) => { %>
    <% if (index < 10) { %>
     <div>
      <p><%= formatDateI(review.createdAt) %></p>
      <p><%= review.comment %></p>
      <p><%= review.name %></p>
     </div>
   <% } %>
   <% }) %>
<% } %>
```